# Swiftmailer "Basic Usage" results in Uncaught ArgumentCountError: Too few arguments

Tags: composer-php, swiftmailer

The Swiftmailer [introduction](https://swiftmailer.symfony.com/docs/introduction.html) (2020-04-21) provides instructions like:

```
$ composer require "swiftmailer/swiftmailer:^6.0"
```

Then use Swiftmailer like so

```
require_once '/path/to/vendor/autoload.php';

// Create the Transport
$transport = (new Swift_SmtpTransport('smtp.example.org', 25));
```

However this results in an error like the following:

```
PHP Fatal error:  Uncaught ArgumentCountError: Too few arguments to function Swift_Transport_EsmtpTransport::__construct(), 0 passed in /app/vendor/swiftmailer/swiftmailer/lib/classes/Swift/SmtpTransport.php on line 35 and at least 3 expected in /app/vendor/swiftmailer/swiftmailer/lib/classes/Swift/Transport/EsmtpTransport.php:54
```

## System

PHP 7.3.10

Composer version 1.9.1

Swiftmailer v6.2.3

Answer (score 0):

The error seems to come from Composer adding its autoloader ahead of  Swiftmailer's autoloader. Swiftmailer makes a point of lazy loading its classes since email is usually only needed on a few areas of a site.

When `Swift_SmtpTransport` is loaded, Composer loads a lightweight placeholder for Swift (which via dependency injection seems to provide a class for `Swift_SmtpTransport`) but Swiftmail's loader does not get a chance to load the real class for `Swift_SmtpTransport`.

A workaround is to explicitly run Swiftmail's autoloader:

```
require_once '/path/to/vendor/autoload.php';
// a single autoload function call seems adequate
// (but this isn't well tested.)
Swift::autoload("Swift_SmtpTransport");


// Create the Transport
$transport = (new Swift_SmtpTransport('smtp.example.org', 25)) 
// ... and so on
```